# What is with() in Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php doing?

Tags: php, laravel-4, deobfuscation, illuminate-container

I'll explain why in a second, but at the moment I'm trying to grok line 606 of `Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php` in Laravel 4:

```
$response = with($stack = $this->getStackedClient())->handle($request);
```

Where is `with()` defined?

If it's a PHP a function or language construct that I'm unfamiliar with, it seems invulnerable to searching on PHP.net, and if not I have no idea where to look for it within the Illuminate package.  I've determined that my current project is failing silently on that line (only on the production server, mind you, not my development server), and if I'm going to trace the crash any further I need to know where `with()` is so I can travel further down the rabbit hole.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers all the way at the bottom of the page

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot.  I'll need to remember those.  I imagine they'd work the same in 4.